# Validating Xml in PCL

Tags: xml, xsd, portable-class-library

I'm porting a library over from .Net 3.5 to a PCL.  Initially, the code used XmlDocument, XmlElement, etc. and it was fairly easy to port over to XDocument, XElement, etc.

The big sticking point right now is validating against an xsd.  It looks like the PCL does not have the XmlSchemaSet type, the XmlReaderSettings type does not have the ValidationType or Schemas properties, and the XmlReader type does not have the SchemaInfo property, etc.

Is there a better way to validate xml with XDocument or is this the case where you have to provide an interface with the specific platforms providing an implementation?